# How can i Insert the whole HTML file with styles when sending email

Tags: c#, html, email

I want to send an email. I have the HTML template which i want to use to send email.I will pass some data from the text boxes Just like confirmation email with your details if you registered on a system. I can't get the format inserted or added as it is giving errors

Here is what i have:

```
    public void SendingEmails()
    {
      string emailbody = string.Empty;
        string mapfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.htm");

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mapfile))
        {
            if (reader == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("File is null");
            }
            emailbody = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        emailbody = emailbody.Replace("{Url}", _Url);






        string Username = "********";
        string Password = "********";
        string host = "********";
        string FromEmailAddress = "********";
        string ToEmailAddress = "********";
        string emailBody = string.Empty;

    var _mail = new MailMessage();
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Host = host;
            smtp.Timeout = 8900000;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            _mail.From = new MailAddress(FromEmailAddress);
            _mail.To.Add(ToEmailAddress);
            _mail.Subject = "Email Confirmation";
            eBody = emailBody.ToString();
            _mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(_mail);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can put html content in one file and read in one varible and after you can manipulate that

Comment: What error is it showing? and is it a compilation error?

Comment: can you please show me the example looking at what i have done so far. I have no idea on how i can do that

Comment: My suggestion would be to keep the html template in a file and populate it later in time.

You can even write the template following razor template and populate it using [razorengine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Comment: @Mr_Hmp I can't get the html work as it shows error all over

Comment: That is because you are writing the complete HTML in one line. I will recommend you to write this HTML in a file and read the content from that HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have the HTML in multiple lines and then there are double quotes `"` within the HTML. You can resolve it by using **@** as a string formatter for multiple lines, And changing all the double quotes inside your HTML to **single quotes** `'`. **Or** for some reason if you still need to use double quotes inside your HTML then just **escape its meaning by using a backslash** `\"`

I have cleaned up the code for you. Just copy paste this into your code.

```
string emailBody = @"<div class='WordSection1'>
       < table cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' align = 'left >
                 < tr >
                     < td width = '0' height = '0' ></ td >
                    </ tr >
                    < tr >

                       < td width = '762' height = '1091' style = 'border:1.0pt solid goldenrod;vertical-align:top' >
                             < spanz - index:251658240'>
                               < table width = '90%;' style = 'margin:1em;' >
                                       < tr >
                                           < td >
                                               < div class='shape'>
                                <div><img src = 'cid:imageId' height='50px' style='padding-right:1em; float:right;'></div><p><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>


            <p style = 'font-family:Calibri' >< tr >< td width='50%'><img alt = '' hspace='0' src='' align='baseline' border='0'>
                                    Dear Call Centre,
                               </p>
                               <p><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p> 
                               <p style = 'font-family:Calibri' >< tr >< td width='50%'>
                                    This communication serves to notify you that the below claim has been registered on the system:
                               </p>

                                <p><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>    

                                <p><b>Date Submitted</b> : txtDate, 2016</p>
                                <p><b>Insurer</b> : txtMac<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </span></p>

                                <p><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                                <p style = 'background:lightsteelblue; width:60%' >< b >
                                    < span style='font-size:12.0pt;color:#b8860b;font-family:' Cambria?,?serif?;?=''>Claim Information</span></b>
                                </p>

        <table class='MsoNormalTable' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
        <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;page-break-inside:avoid' >
        < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
        <p><span class='SpellE'>PNumber</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width = '378' valign='top' style='width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
        <p>txtNumber</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
            <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:2;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Name</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign='top' style='width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>txtName</p>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:3;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Broker Email Address</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign='top' style='width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>txtEmail</p>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:4;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Tel</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign='top' style='width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>txtTel</p>
                </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:8;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Incident Date</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > txtInceptiodate </ p >
                </ td >
                </ tr >
                < tr style= 'mso-yfti-irow:9;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > Range </ p >
                </ td >
                < td width= '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > txtRange </ p >
                </ td >
                </ tr >
                </ table >

                < p >< o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                <p style = 'background:lightsteelblue; width:60%' >< b >< span style='font-size:
                12.0pt;color:#b8860b;font-family:' Cambria?,?serif?;?=''>The
                Insured<o:p></o:p></span></b></p>

                <table class='MsoNormalTable' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border-collapse:collapse;mso-padding-alt:0in 0in 0in 0in'>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Insured Name</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > NOC N DROP</p>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:1;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > Contact Person</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p >< span class='SpellE'>N</span></p>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:2;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width='189' valign='top' style='width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt'>
                <p>Identity Number</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > 0 </ p >
                </ td >
                </ tr >
                < tr style= 'mso-yfti-irow:3;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > Suburb </ p >
                </ td >
                < td width= '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p > George, George, Western Cape</p>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:4;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                < p >< span class='SpellE'>Fitment</span> Branch</p>
                </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > Wise Cracks</p>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style = 'mso-yfti-irow:5;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                   < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > Cellphone Numbers</p>
                   </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > 0413740740 </ p >
                   </ td >
                   </ tr >
                   < tr style= 'mso-yfti-irow:6;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                   < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > Business Number</p>
                   </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > 0413740740 </ p >
                   </ td >
                   </ tr >
                   < tr style= 'mso-yfti-irow:7;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes;page-break-inside:avoid' >
                   < td width= '189' valign= 'top' style= 'width:141.75pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > Home Number</p>
                   </td>
                <td width = '378' valign= 'top' style= 'width:283.45pt;padding:0in 3.4pt 0in 3.4pt' >
                   < p > 0448751000 </ p >
                   </ td >
                   </ tr >
                   </ table >
                   </ table >
                   </ div > '";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is sending blank email with only subject

Answer (score 0):

This is a mess.

First of all, you're gonna wanna strip that HTML code of all line breaks and place it into a single line.

Next,  you're going to want to escape your string by prepending a backslash to every instance of a quotation mark within your string. (This will stop the compiler from thinking you've ended your string).

See example:

```
var escapedString = "The woman said: \"Hello, young man.\"";
```

Then, you're gonna want to use some form of string formatting to include all of those other variables within the HTML string. (I recommend string interpolation)